# Resize QTextEdit in a QWidget while it is being resized the QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, resize

How to make QTextEdit to be resized in a QWidget while the QWidget is being resized? 
Should I overload resizeEvent function for the QWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should set the [sizePolicy property](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) for your QTextEdit object.

Comment: In addition to this, you also need to have the text edit be inside a layout of the containing widget, all the way up to the main widget that is being resized.

Answer (score 3):

You should use layouts too achive this. There is an excellent tutorial by the trolls on how to do this: http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/layout.html.